# Combining four factor scores into one composite scale

Tags: r, factor-analysis, composite

Is it possible to use exploratory factor analysis to extract four factors, and then combine these four factors (i.e. the factor scores for each observation) into a composite scale?

Comment: Look into second order (or higher order) factor analysis. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is another instance of this question: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133492 I don't think you can meaningfully combine several factor/PC scores.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
Exploratory factor analysis aims to reducing data to a smaller set of summary variables... which are not the initial factors. But, depending on the EFA you used, you can use, for instance, a linear model based on the EFA score to reduce some factors in one.
But, you should discrib a little bit more what analysis you think to use.

Comment: This is perhaps more of a comment than an actual answer. Perhaps you could develop your answer a little bit (e.g. detail what the "linear model" would be, give an example, etc.), or move your answer to the commentary section.

Comment: You're right, but I need 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: And I found this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22665/how-to-integrate-principal-components-with-glm