# Feature selection for MLP in sklearn: Is using PCA or LDA advisable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I have a binary supervised classification problem with about 62 features, by eye about 30 of them could have reasonable discriminating power. I am using sklearn and the MLP does not have a dedicated feature selection tool like decision trees do.
My question is what is the recommended way to preform feature selection here? 
I have read in the sklearn documentation that LDA should not be performed in a binary classification problem and PCA is under the unsupervised methods on the sklearn website.

Does anyone have any experience with this that could suggest a method?

(P.S. Apologies if this question isn't up to standard, this is my first question ever asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- One important reason to use neural network is that, the model can do "feature selection and feature engineering" automatically for us. Unless we have a huge problem (say millions features), it is not necessary to use feature selection for neural network.
- Using PCA for feature selection on supervised learning is a bad practice, since it does not consider the "correlation" between feature and label, and direct select feature with large variance. In other words, we can have a completely useless feature but with large variance in data, and PCA will select it. See my answer here for details [How to decide between PCA and logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244677/how-to-decide-between-pca-and-logistic-regression/244680#244680)